# how can i have two barer token in header using akka http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

i have an app in akka http i am using its header directive for using accessToken as barer token everything is working fine , now i want to have two barer token instead of one, first should be accessToken and second should be a refreshToken

here is my working code for one barer token

```
private def bearerToken: Directive1[Option[String]] =
    for {
      authBearerHeader <- optionalHeaderValueByType(classOf[Authorization]).map(extractBearerToken)
      xAuthCookie <- optionalCookie("X-Authorization-Token").map(_.map(_.value))
    } yield authBearerHeader.orElse(xAuthCookie)


  private def extractBearerToken(authHeader: Option[Authorization]): Option[String] =
    authHeader.collect {
      case Authorization(OAuth2BearerToken(token)) => token
    }
```

a route defined in my main controller

```
def accessProtectedResource: server.Route =
   path("access-protected-resource") {
      get {
        bearerToken { accessToken =>
          accessToken match {
            case Some(token) =>
            case Failure(e)=>failWith(ex)
         }
      }
}
```

and from postman i added barer token in Authorization tab of postman

can anyone please guide what changes i need to make if i need to pass two barer token (accessToken and refreshToken)

Comment: Why would you want to pass a refresh token as a bearer token for APIs? Access token should be enough for API calls, refresh token is usually used as part of oauth2 refresh flow.

Comment: If you need to pass refresh token to the client, then I would suggest an HTTP-only, secure cookie.